# Woocommerce Product Image function is bypassing sites character encoding and breaking Scandinavian characters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, character-encoding, special-characters

So I'm in a bit of a situation.
Currently I'm doing support on a Danish Woocommerce webshop, and we've run into a quiet specific problem.

The problem occurs when a product is shown on a single-product site, where specifically the '`title`' belonging to the product image breaks Danish special characters, æ ø å into `Ã¦ Ã¸ Ã¥`. Every charset setting on the site, database and server are set to `UTF-8`, but the function which instantiates the product image seemingly doesn't support multibyte characters.

From my knowledge this is the function in question:

```
function wc_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_id, $main_image = false ) {
$flexslider        = (bool) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', get_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' ) );
$gallery_thumbnail = wc_get_image_size( 'gallery_thumbnail' );
$thumbnail_size    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', array( $gallery_thumbnail['width'], $gallery_thumbnail['height'] ) );
$image_size        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_image_size', $flexslider || $main_image ? 'woocommerce_single' : $thumbnail_size );
$full_size         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'full' ) );
$thumbnail_src     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $thumbnail_size );
$full_src          = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $full_size );
$alt_text          = trim( wp_strip_all_tags( get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ) ) );
$image             = wp_get_attachment_image(
    $attachment_id,
    $image_size,
    false,
    apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params',
        array(
            'title'                   => _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_title', $attachment_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
            'data-caption'            => _wp_specialchars( get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $attachment_id ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true ),
            'data-src'                => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
            'data-large_image'        => esc_url( $full_src[0] ),
            'data-large_image_width'  => esc_attr( $full_src[1] ),
            'data-large_image_height' => esc_attr( $full_src[2] ),
            'class'                   => esc_attr( $main_image ? 'wp-post-image' : '' ),
        ),
        $attachment_id,
        $image_size,
        $main_image
    )
);

return '<div data-thumb="' . esc_url( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '" data-thumb-alt="' . esc_attr( $alt_text ) . '" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="' . esc_url( $full_src[0] ) . '">' . $image .  '</a></div>';
```

}

It seems to me like one of the **`apply_filters()`** functions breaks the strings found in the array, specifically '`title`' and '`data-caption`'.

For now, I've performed a temporary fix on the site, doing a simple search and replace in the database, replacing every æ, ø and å with the corresponding HTML-code: `&aring;` etc.
But this doesn't change the problem in the long run, when new products are added to the database.

From what I've found, this is not a common issue, but hopefully someone smarter than me will chime in with a potential fix.

Comment: How are those `æ ø å` broken/transformed? Please [edit] the question and add that info to your [mcve] (I'd guess `Ã¦ Ã¸ Ã¥`)?

Comment: Why do you call the [`_wp_specialchars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_specialchars/) function?  I'd omit it at all as `array( 'title' => get_post_field( 'post_title', $attachment_id ),
'data-caption'  => get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $attachment_id ), …`. (Another chance: pass `$double_encode` as `false` instead of `true`).

Comment: So i failed to mention that this code snippet is all stock template code from Woocommerce, and i have not done any changes to it. I'll try out your suggestions first thing in the morning. Cheers.